# Switch from zip to ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm using php8; The problem is that a little part of an extended script still using zip_open. I'm trying to redo this peace of code with ZipArchive. But i don't know if this is the right way to do?

The original Code:

```php
if ($ext == 'zip' && function_exists('zip_open')) {
   $arch = zip_open($path);
   if ($arch) {
       $filenames = array();
       while ($zip_entry = zip_read($arch)) {
           $zip_name = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
           $zip_folder = substr($zip_name, -1) == '/';
           $filenames[] = array(
               'name' => $zip_name,
               'filesize' => zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry),
               'compressed_size' => zip_entry_compressedsize($zip_entry),
               'folder' => $zip_folder
               //'compression_method' => zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry),
               );
           }
           zip_close($arch);
        return $filenames;
```

**UPDATE!**
i've this now :

```php
if ($ext == 'zip' && function_exists('ZipArchive')) {
    $za = new ZipArchive();
    $arch = $za->open($path);
    if ($arch) {
        $filenames = array();
        while ($zip_entry = $za->numFiles) {
            $zip_name = $zip->getNameIndex($zip_entry);
            $zip_folder = substr($zip_name, -1) == '/';
            $filenames[] = array(
                'name' => $zip_name,'filesize' => $zip->getNameIndex($zip_entry)->filesize(),
                'compressed_size' => $zip->getNameIndex($zip_entry)->compressed_size(),
                'folder' => $zip_folder
                //'compression_method' => zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry),
            );
    }
    $za->close();
    return $filenames;
```

Comment: What does "ends in chaos" mean? Please be specific about what problem you are having and which part of your code is causing it.

Comment: I was searching for a way to get filesize, compressed size enz. in ZipArchive.

I think i found a way, after a few hours... statIndex['name'],statIndex['size'], statIndex['comp_size'], enz.